# Non-Cryogenic Propellant Transfer

Tags: fuel, refueling, hypergolics

I know there are programs like the Rocket Lab CryoSat, but I was wondering if there have been any tests of non-cryo propellant transfer?
I know the Space Station refuels with a storable hypergol, but otherwise?

Comment: AFAIK it's only been hypergols. There wouldn't be much point in xferring RP-1 or similar since it typically uses a cryo oxidizer.

Comment: potentially helpful will be other questions tagged with [tag:refueling] and [tag:restore-l] and their answers.